# just trying to grasp the basics

Tags: while-loop

hey i know this is going to sound "noobish" but i am wondering if i have a issue with my computer i am trying to create a counter going from 1 to 10 using an while statement can you do that? if so is this the way to do it

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
Dim count as integer = 10
While a < count
Label1.Text = (a).ToString
a = a + 1
End While
```

I set this up with a button and it goes straight to 10 it does not increment by 1. maybe I have vb.net confused with python... idk.....any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, what language are you actually writing/ trying to write in? VB.NET or Python or another one? Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out gotta use a timer